# Regex: math and substitute strings?

Tags: regex

I have part of a regex match expression going; I'm stuck on the part where I need to match symbols and replace them with their opposite symbol. So if I get an input string < I have to replace it with > and <= replaced with >= and vice versa....but I'm confused not sure how to do this.

I can only accept a string that does have one of these valid operators.

So far this is my regex:

```
(\w+)(\s)*([(?P<less><)?(?P<greater>>)?(?P<gEqual>>=)?(?P<lEqual><=]) . 
(\s*)*(\w+)
```

^^Problem with this is that it's not matching the <= or >=

This is my substitution string, which is obviously not complete but I can't even get it to sub in part of the problem:

```
\5\b<\b(?=>)\1
```

Also,
I am using regex101.com to check my stuff.
Please help!

a < b should turn into b > a
asda     <=c should turn into c > asda

Comment: Depending on your language, could you use a custom replacement function in conjunction with or instead of regex? Simplified example in JS using a couple of operators: `"a < b asda <=c 6 > 3".replace(/([<>])/g, m => { return { ">": "<", "<": ">" }[m]; });`

Comment: Write a parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick to match all your operators:

```
(?<less><(?!=))|(?<lEqual><=)|(?<greater>(?<!=)>)|(?<gEqual>=>)
```

It uses a negative look ahead to prevent capturing the 'less than or equal' operator in the 'less' capturing group. Likewise it uses negative look behind to prevent capturing the 'greater than or equal' operator in the the 'greater than' capturing group.

AFAICT it at least matches your example as you can see at https://regex101.com/r/GvB7nA/1

Comment: Awesome! It passes the matching. Do you have any advice on how to do substitution, for conditionals? Like, if matches < do > or is there something easier?

Comment: AFAIK you can not do that in the regular expression itself, you will need to do that in your code as regular expressions only provide you the logic to do the matching not the replacement.
I am not so sure if you really need regular expressions for this as @ggorlen already suggested.